# How many ordered triples $(A,B,C)$ of subsets of ${1,2,...,n}$ exists in this conditions?

Tags: combinatorics

The question that I have is:

**How many ordered triples $(A,B,C)$ of subsets of ${1,2,...,n}$ exists such that $A\cap B\cap C = \varnothing$, $A\cap B \neq \varnothing$ and $A\cap C \neq \varnothing$?**

The problem is the answer that i got. It starts saying that if i fix $k$ as the number of elements in $A\cap B\ (1 \leq k \leq n)$ and $j$ as the number in $A\cap C\ (1 \leq j \leq n - k)$, then we will have  ${n}\choose{k}$ ways to choose the $k$ elements, and ${n-k}\choose{j}$ ways to choose the $j$ element. So far so good, i understand all that is said from the start to here.

But now, the answer says that we have $5$ permitted regions for the other $n-k-j$ elements, in the way that the answer is: $\sum^n_{k=1}\sum^{n-k}_{j=1} {{n}\choose{k}} {{n-k}\choose{j}}5^{n-k-j}$.

And then, after that, the answer develops untill the point that we get the answer $7^n - 2\cdot6^n + 5^n$. The arithimetical work to get here i understood as well.

What i don't get at all is the $5$ regions. First of all, the therm "regions" doesn't get explained anywhere, but i guessed they are $B\cap C$, exclusive $A$, exclusive $B$, exclusive $C$ or $A\cap B \cap C$, but this interpretation doesn't makes sense to me because no elements can be included in $A \cap B \cap C$. So, either i'm not seeing something here or i interpreted "regions" wrongly.

Could someone help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

You have the right general idea about the regions, but the details aren’t quite right. The possibilities are:

- $[n]\setminus(A\cup B\cup C)$ (i.e., none of $A,B$, and $C$)
- $A\setminus(B\cup C)$ (i.e., just $A$)
- $B\setminus(A\cup C)$ (i.e., just $B$)
- $C\setminus(A\cup B)$ (i.e., just $C$)
- $(B\cap C)\setminus A$ (i.e., in both $B$ and $C$ but not in $A$)

Comment: i forgotted that it can be placed in none of the three sets. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Ulivai: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 1):

There are eight regions in the Venn diagram.  You have chosen the number of elements in $A \cap B$ and $A \cap C$.  The problem specifies that the number in $A \cap B \cap C$ is zero.  There are five regions left, and each element can go in any of the five.  The five are $B \cap C$, exclusive $A,B,C$ and outside all three.

Comment: i forgotted that it can be placed in none of the three sets. Thanks a lot!